# How to transition existing divs in yui3 to Overlay bodyContent

Tags: yui3

I've figured out how to create an Overlay, center it, and set it's bodyContent to be an existing  from my page. So far so good - now I want to make the transition happen smoothly over 1 full second instead of instantaneously.

The examples I've seen indicate that one must know the initial and final positions, but in this case, I don't know them, since I'm just saying:

```
overlay.set('bodyContent', Y.one('#node'));
overlay.set('centered', true)
```

I've created a jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ovuxan/5/edit that shows the issue.. (my transition is whacky to say the least) and would appreciate some help in making it smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WidgetAnim` plugin to do this for you. It can be cleaner since the animations are stored in the plugin and invoked by the widget's `hide`/`show` functions.

I have quickly used the plugin to animate your overlay here: http://jsbin.com/ohafec/1/edit

Helpful links:

- [Overlay: Animation Plugin (YUI Blog)](http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.3.0pr3/examples/overlay/overlay-anim-plugin.html)
- [Plugin.WidgetAnim Class](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Plugin.WidgetAnim.html)